# PSU for Ampacity test of connection

Tags: power-electronics, high-current, test, ampacity

i have this problem. I have to validate with a test that my connection on my power board can carry the nominal current required by the specs.

For current around 10A the setup I'm using is a Multioutput Bench PSU with all the output working in constant current mode in parallel, like the following figure:
[image: Ampacity test setup for current up to 10A]

If I need to go up to 100A this approach is not feasible anymore because the Bench PSU are normally limited up to 10A.

What are the PSU used for testing the ampacity for current value of 100A?

Are there any commercial type already available?

Are there any DIY way of doing this?

Comment: Don't close this, I took out the shopping question

Answer (score 1):

My quick and dirty options follow:

1. Use a step down transformer to generate a lower working voltage. i.e. something like 5VAC from 120V. Rectify and use bulk capacitance to allow a large and long enough current pulse for sake of testing.
2. If you require longer testing i.e. seconds or minutes, then I would suggest using common LiPo or Lead Acid batteries in parallel, and an approximate water load (water mixed with baking soda or salt make it conductive.) A 5Gal bucket and two copper pipes in it can handle thousands of watts of power for quite a while.
3. Finally if neither of the above options sound acceptable, then you need to start looking into much more expensive supply options. You could continue doing what you are doing, but add balancing resistors (~0.1 Ohm) in series with each supply. Consider investing in cheap Ebay style SMPS.